# MySqlException when passing table name as a parameter to MySqlCommand

Tags: c#, mysql

I am writing a very simple bit of code and cannot figure out why the parameters are not working on my SQL select.   Any advice would be appreciated.

1. I have a prior connection/select without parameters that works fine
2. I have tried the select in MySQL workbench it is fine (and have simplified it too)
   Here is the relevant code.   There is an exception on the ExecuteReader statement.

This is the result from the locals window:

> - [MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException] {"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server
>     version for the right syntax to use near ''AAIT_N'' at line
>     1"}   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException

```
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connString);
MySqlCommand cmd;
conn.Open();
try
   {
     cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
     cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * from @p ";  
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p", sym);
     string wait = Console.ReadLine();
     MySqlDataReader myresults = cmd.ExecuteReader();   <=== Throws an exception
     if (myresults.HasRows)
etc.
```

Comment: If you are interested in the reason behind this, its because the parameter system escapes/cleans the values it inserts in the SQL. It is inserting your `@p` parameter with quotes, turning it into `SELECT * FROM "AAIT_N"`, including the quotes, which is an invalid table name.

Comment: Thanks Ron, I actually spent 2 hours trying to figure exactly that out (I haven't written serious code in a lot of years), Rahul's response clears up the abstraction I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't pass the table name as parameter. Rather you can do like below

```
 string query = string.Format("SELECT * from {0}", sym);  
 cmd.CommandText = query; 
 MySqlDataReader myresults = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: oooohhhhh fun....

I'll pass "blah; DROP DATABASE blah;"

Comment: Thank you.   It throws a different error now . . .but this solved the problem.   Thank you very much!!

Comment: @DonUnknown this is probably the solution you need. But you may want to verify that sym is not coming from user input in any way before using. Otherwise, you may need to do some sanitization work first.

Comment: @JonathanHenson, that's true, it's open now for SQL Injection but the answer points to the fact that table name can't be passed as parameter. A better solution would be use a procedure with a dynamic query.

Comment: It's only vulnerable if this is being triggered from a UI, web request, or some other sort of input. If there are proper controls in place, it's fine. The writer of this code just needs to make that decision consciously.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan.   No user input here.   my data on a closed system.   A control freak's playground if you will :)   Thanks again.

Comment: I would suggest some kind of reflection to resolve the tablename on runtime.

Comment: @JonathanHenson, Yes but either way; if I had to do this; I would use a procedure which takes table name as parameter and build a dynamic query on that.

Comment: @Rahul, that's certainly the safest approach.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use a table name as a parameter.

```
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connString);
MySqlCommand cmd;
conn.Open();
try
   {
     cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
     cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * from someTable where firstName = @p ";  
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p", "yourValue");
     Console.ReadLine();
     MySqlDataReader myresults = cmd.ExecuteReader();
     if (myresults.HasRows)
etc.
```